# cannot enable wifi of Alienware R2 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: wireless, 16.04, alienware

I just installed 16.04 LTS on my Alienware 15 R2 laptop and can connect to Internet via Ethernet cable but the wifi connection is missing. I tried the solutions posted on [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697621/cannot-use-wifi-on-linux-alienware-14-laptop) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/661424/ubuntu-14-04-wireless-not-working-no-network-interface-atheros-168c003e-dev) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765595/wifi-does-not-work-ubuntu-16-04-on-lenovo-z51-laptop) but none worked. Here are some commands ant outputs that I found people need as details.

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; dmesg | grep iwl
```

output has two parts:

```
3b:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1969:e0a1] (rev 10)
```

Subsystem: Device [0707:2400]

Kernel driver in use: alx

3c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)

Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1a56:1535]

Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci

Kernel modules: ath10k_pci

---

```
uname -a
```

output is:

```
Linux Alien 4.4.0-21-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 18:33:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

---

```
dmesg | grep ath
```

output is:

```
[    2.150461] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
```

[    2.152447] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: pci irq msi-x interrupts 8 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0

[    2.407236] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:3c:00.0.bin failed with error -2

[    2.407419] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin failed with error -2

[    2.407420] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin': -2

[    2.470759] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin failed with error -2

[    4.592601] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 (0x05030000, 0x00340aff sub 1a56:1535) fw WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 fwapi 4 bdapi 1 htt-ver 3.26 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1 features wowlan,ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad

[    4.592604] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0

[    5.589080] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: suspend timed out - target pause event never came

[    5.656734] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x6c

[    5.656735] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map

[    5.656737] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00

[    5.656737] ath: Regpair used: 0x6c

[    5.661209] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0 wlp60s0: renamed from wlan0

[   10.921203] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11

[   16.921320] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)

[   22.233444] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11

[   28.233395] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)

[   33.549654] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11

[   39.549782] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)

[   55.146292] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11

[   61.133146] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)

[   66.439941] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11

[   72.437145] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)

[   88.102935] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11

[   94.102625] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)

[   99.410363] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11

[  105.410204] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)

[  121.094102] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11

[  127.093979] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)

---

```
ls /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0
```

output is:

```
board.bin  firmware-4.bin  notice_ath10k_firmware-4.txt
```

Comment: `sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k_core.conf` and edit question to include `ls /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0`

Comment: @Jeremy31 just added the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a board-2.bin file

```
cd /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0
sudo wget https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/raw/master/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin
```

Reboot